# Yearweek is parsed wrongly in R

Tags: r, date

**Problem**: I am facing the problem that R parses a date (30 December 2019) into yearweek wrongly (Output: 2019 W01). I do not know why this is happening. Any suggestions what to change/alternative way of coding?

```
format(lubridate::ymd("2019-12-30"), "%Y W%V")
# Output
# 2019 W01

# Desired Output:
# 2019 W52
```

Comment: Everything is correct, because 30-12-2019 was a Monday and officially is week 1: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found that this is the best solution:

```
format(lubridate::ymd("2019-12-30"), "%G W%V")
```

Use `%G` instead of `%Y` to reflect that the week-based year (`%G` and `%g`) may differ from the calendar year (`%Y` and `%y`).

See also: https://community.rstudio.com/t/converting-week-number-and-year-into-date/27202/2

Answer (score 1):

From the [strptime documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html):

```
%U
    Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the first day 1 of the 
    week (and typically with the first Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The US
    convention.

%V
    Week of the year as decimal number (01–53) as defined in ISO 8601. If the week
    (starting on Monday) containing 1 January has four or more days in the new year,
    then it is considered week 1. Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year, 
    and the next week is week 1. (Accepted but ignored on input.)

%W
    Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first day of week
    (and typically with the first Monday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The UK 
    convention.
```

It sounds like you may want either `%U` or `%W`, depending on whether you want to treat Sunday or Monday as the start of the week.

Note however that these can result in values between `00` and `53`, which is a consequence of fixing the start of the week to a particular weekday (either Sunday or Monday).  Doing that means that there can actually be a partial week at the start and at the end of the year.

If you prefer to count based on week number 1 beginning on the first day of the year, you can use the function `lubridate::week`.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)
year_week <- function(date) paste0(year(date), ' W', week(date))

year_week(ymd("2019-01-01"))
# Result: "2019 W1"

year_week(ymd("2019-12-30"))
# Result: "2019 W52"
```

Comment: Or if you prefer always having a 2-digit week, replace `week(date)` with  `stringr::str_pad(week(date), 2, pad = '0')` in the above example.